How to filter collection based on key?
I have a collection which is like this:
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#456 ▼ // app\Http\Controllers\UserController.php:42
  #items: array:4 [▼
    0 => array:10 [▼
      "to" => "12145"
      "from" => "1833"
      "type" => "MMS"
      "smsCount" => 3
      "status" => "PENDING"
      "error" => "No Error"
      "description" => "Message sent, waiting for delivery report"
      "sentAt" => "2024-04-06T05:29:20.791Z"
      "doneAt" => "2024-04-06T05:29:22.779Z"
      "messageId" => "27a13e81"
    ]
    1 => array:10 [▼
      "to" => "1215"
      "from" => "18334"
      "type" => "MMS"
      "smsCount" => 3
      "status" => "DELIVERED"
      "error" => "No Error"
      "description" => "Message delivered to handset"
      "sentAt" => "2024-04-06T05:26:44.683Z"
      "doneAt" => "2024-04-06T05:26:46.423Z"
      "messageId" => "ebb9330c"
    ]
    2 => array:10 [▶]
    3 => array:10 [▶]
  ]
  #escapeWhenCastingToString: false
} 

I want to filter arrays based on the type (which could be MMS or SMS) and the month from sendAt. I need to send this data to Chart.js. Therefore, I need to filter the type and count the number of MMS and SMS sent each month. How can I group the collection? I tried the following method, but I didn't get the desired output.
$selectedElements = new Collection($selectedElements);
$filteredAndGrouped = $selectedElements
          ->where('type', 'MMS')
          ->groupBy(function ($item) {
                    // Extract year and month from the date string
        $dateParts = explode('-', substr($item['sentAt'], 0, 10)); // Extract yyyy-mm from the date string
                   return $dateParts[0] . '-' . $dateParts[1]; // Return yyyy-mm format
 });

I want to display an output like [0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] in Chart.js. This means that I have four MMS in April and none in the other months. If there are any MMS in other months, they should be placed in their respective positions. How can I achieve this output?

"couldn't get appropriate output" You should give an example of what you expect.

"Grouping" and "filtering" are two distinctly different actions.  Please only ask clear, unique question with a [mcve].

Laravel Eloquent, group by month/year and Laravel collection - Group by months in a year and show the missing months from table with a count of 0 and Group by month and years eloquent laravel and Laravel group by date to month only and get count

@Olivier I want to show output like [0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] to chartjs Means in april I have four mms and other months with no mms. If there it will place there. How can i get that output?

You don't need Laravel collections for that. It's just basic PHP array manipulation.

You have to parse your sendAt using Carbon and then return the formatted date as month and year
$filteredAndGrouped = $selectedElements
        ->where('type', 'MMS')
        ->groupBy(function ($item) {
            // parse the datetime string into carbon object
            $dateParts = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($item['sendAt']);
            return $dateParts->format('Y-m');
        })
    


The result is exactly the same, it's just an alternative implementation. Personnaly I would just use substr($item['sentAt'], 0, 7).

if you want a combination of type and date,you can append substr($item['sentAt'], 0, 7).' '.$item['type']  in the type in return in that way you will get two types of filter of same month

And to check wether a group is of MMS/SMS type you can check first or [0] index type

I want to show output like [0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] Means in april I have four mms and other months with no mms. If there it will place there.
How can i get that output?
